# How do I only output unique taxonomy terms?

Tags: php, wordpress

The below code is querying the apartmentlocation taxonomy, and then inside of that I'm looping through and grabbing all the apartmentlevel taxonomy assigned to each apartment. The problem is that $itemLevels is outputing double ups. So for example I'm getting Level 1 twice becuase it's assigned to two apartment levels. But I want it to check if this Level 1 has already been outputted and skip it.

I think I need to store all itemLevels into an array and then only output the unique, but I don't know how to do that.

In desperate need of some help, please.

```
  <?php
    $custom_terms = get_terms('apartmentlocation');

    foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) :
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array('post_type' => 'apartment',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'apartmentlocation',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                    
                ),
            
            ),
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
        
        <div>
            <p class="floorplates__description"><?php echo $custom_term->description ?></p>

            <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                $itemLevels = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'apartmentlevel');
                $itemBedrooms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'apartmentbedroom');
                foreach ($itemLevels as $itemLevel) {
                    $itemLevel = $itemLevel->slug;
                }
                foreach ($itemBedrooms as $itemBedroom) {
                    $itemBedroom = $itemBedroom->slug;
                }
            ?>

            <span><?php echo $itemLevel; ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $itemBedroom; ?></span>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a><br>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>
        <?php
        endif;
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push term slug into an array and then you can check with `in_array()`.

```
<?php
$custom_terms = get_terms('apartmentlocation');

$itemLevel_arr = array();

foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) :

    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'apartment',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'apartmentlocation',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                
            ),
        
        ),
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
    
    <div>
        <p class="floorplates__description"><?php echo $custom_term->description ?></p>

        <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
            $itemLevels = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'apartmentlevel');
            $itemBedrooms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'apartmentbedroom');
            foreach ($itemLevels as $itemLevel) {
                $itemLevel = $itemLevel->slug;
            }
            foreach ($itemBedrooms as $itemBedroom) {
                $itemBedroom = $itemBedroom->slug;
            }

        if( !in_array( $itemLevel, $itemLevel_arr ) ){ 
            $itemLevel_arr[] = $itemLevel;
            ?>
            <span><?php echo $itemLevel; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <span><?php echo $itemBedroom; ?></span>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a><br>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;
    endforeach;


?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that works, maybe I'm being dumb though... 
I'm looping through all posts that have a apartmentlocation taxonomy, I then have another loop inside of that that's looping through and get the apartmentlevel taxonomy value for each of those posts. Problem is I don't know how to store the apartmentlevels in an array and remove the duplicates then output all levels... Maybe I'm not making sense and maybe your solution is correct, I'm just super confused at the moment..